# Entries to the database automatically after reload the web site

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

( Sorry for my bad english )

I am new to PHP. I have two input fields. One for the username and one for the comment. My problem is when I Reloaded my page that simply blank entries I posted my table. Why is that?

Existing Code :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','holycms');

if(!db){
   exit ("Verbindungsfehler:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO feedback (username, comment) VALUES ('$username', '$comment')";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $eintrag);
```

Comment: Probably because you're not using `isset()` on a submit button and/or the code's execution. Show some code ;) Use conditional statements.

Comment: `$username = $_POST['username'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$db = mysqli_connect( 
 'localhost',
 'root',
 '',
 'holycms' );
 
if(!db) {
 exit ("Verbindungsfehler:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO feedback (username, comment) VALUES ('$username', '$comment')";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $eintrag);`

Comment: Please place your (full) code in your question, it's very hard to read it in comments.

Comment: sorry, but i don't know how i put my code in a code break.

Comment: So, now its in a code break. Thanks to Jay!

Comment: Consult my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that your code is coming from a POST form, you can use a conditional statement around it.

For example, in your HTML form:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

then use:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','holycms');

    if(!db){
       exit ("Verbindungsfehler:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO feedback (username, comment) VALUES ('$username', '$comment')";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $eintrag);

}
```

another thing is to make sure that fields are not left empty, using `empty()` I.e.:

```
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
  echo "Enter a username.";
    exit;
}
```

also `isset()`. I.e.:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  // do something
}
```

You can also use a `header("Location: http://www.example.com/page.php");`

but make sure there is nothing else above your PHP, echo, HTML, etc.

---

In regards to your present code:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *it's much safer.*